# Fill UILabel text to fill its width

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing a photo application with some editing options so I have a UIView and it is resizable and in that UIView I have UILabel with the UIView bounds as rect. I want to increase the font of text when I resize the view. I tried sizeToFit,factLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth as TRUE but its not working I want to fill the text to its frame. can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

change the property AutoShrink to minimum font as above Arik Said

[image: Autoshrink]

Answer (score 1):

In Storyboard, go to the label's attributes inspector.
You should make the font VERY big (think hundreds of points), and in the "Autoshrink" section choose a minimum font size (as small as you want).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add this:

label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 0;

Then the text will automatically resize to fit the label.

Comment: I already used this but it will FIT the text font to its frame but I want to FILL the text to its frame.

Comment: I am looking to fill the text to the frame size like all borders of the text should be filled in the frame